# Subversion: Rename all folders containing specific characters

Tags: svn, rename

is it possible to rename all folders containing specific characters?

As an example of what I want to achieve:

I want to rename:

This_is_a_folder

This_is_another_folder

To:

Thisisafolder

Thisisanotherfolder

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same command parameters you would use for command `mv` for command `svn mv` in a working copy.

For your example:

```
$ svn mv "This_is_a_folder" "$(echo This_is_a_folder | sed 's/_//')"
```

or if all your folders to rename are in the same parent folder:

```
$ for a in ./*; do svn mv "$a" "$(echo "$a" | sed 's/_//')"; done
```